# Opening QFileDialog shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp

Tags: qt, shell, qt-creator, qfiledialog, comdlg32

I have a problem with `QFileDialog`. I used this code:

```
fileDialog = new QFileDialog(this);
fileDialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
fileDialog->setReadOnly(true);

if (fileDialog->exec()){
    ui->FilePath->setText(fileDialog->directoryUrl().toString());
}
```

In application `out`, it told me this:

> shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(9456)\comdlg32.dll!00007FF9A3A2260A:
>   (caller: 00007FF9A3A2A866) ReturnHrPreRelease tid(2110) 80070490
>   Élément introuvable.
>
> CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop\InitDialog\FileDialogInitEnterpriseData]

I use Qt creator 3.5.0 and Qt5.5.0 on Windows 10.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been answered in the following thread :

[How to debug …\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628821/how-to-debug-comdlg32-fileopensave-cpp)

TLDR : not an issue. message is an extra debug message from win10 api.